# how to override method on my app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i use this in app delegate to provide rotation to all the view but in one view not all i need to override this method so the view support only the portrait view

Method (delegate.m)

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait  | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the methods available for [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) itself?

You could use these methods in your particular class according to the orientation you need.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

In your AppDelegate, you are already having this method, you don't need it anywhere else.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window

{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

From Apple Docs

> This method returns the interface orientations to use for any view controllers that do not specify their own explicitly. The orientations returned by this method are used if the view controller does not override the supportedInterfaceOrientations or shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method.
>
> If you do not implement this method, the application uses the values in the UIInterfaceOrientation key of the app’s Info.plist as the default interface orientations.

**Update if using `UINavigationController`**

In this case you need to implement the custom `UINavigationController` because your `navigationController` might disturb the interface orientations you have provided for different viewcontrollers.

**CutomNavigationController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CutomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

**CutomNavigationController.m**

```
#import "CutomNavigationController.h"


@interface CutomNavigationController ()

@end

@implementation CutomNavigationController

//overriding shouldRotate method for working in navController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    
  return   [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
    
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

      return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation]; 
}
```

Finally use this `CustomNavigationController` in your `AppDelegate`, this will be referenced as your `navigationcontroller` for all the viewcontrollers

Comment: if i use these method without the method on the delegate it doesn't rotate

Comment: please describe more how can i use them

Comment: I have added method in the answer, you should use only supported orientations mask. check the updated answer

Comment: ok but how can i stop one view from rotate say: i need view to be only portrait how can i do that

Comment: the previous provide rotation for all the views

Comment: use this method `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{return NO;}` and return no for the controller where you want to stop rotation

Comment: i use it but it still rotate in landscape

Comment: post your code, it should not rotate if you set the autorotate to NO

Comment: i put log to see if it call shouldautorotate

Comment: You are using navigation controller in your App ?

Comment: in that case your orientations are disturbed by the naigation controller. I can suggest you to implement a custom uinavigationcontroller and add these methods in that class, i can update the code in  few minutes so that you can use that in your app

Answer (score 0):

This should all be handled in the view controller.  Use the UIViewController method:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{}
```